# How to replace Include / ThenInclude in EF Core with joins?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Example

```
_context.Actors
        .Include(actor => actor.Movies)
        .ThenInclude(movie => movie.MovieInfo)
```

As I know `Include` operation is designed to preserve the original object structures and graphs. On the other hand, a Join operation becomes necessary when projecting a flattened representation of the object graph or when joining types that aren't inherently connected through the graph.

Just want to know what is right way to do that. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i'm pretty sure you can find plenty of examples of joining two or more tables with a LINQ query stackoverflow.com/questions/11204367/… –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Include` and `Join` essentially do the same thing and result in `JOIN`s within the generated SQL. `Include` just eager loads the entities related by navigation properties, `Join` is used in the rare cases where you want to return unrelated, or loosely related entities. Loosely related tables being tables that use something like an OwnerType + OwnerId association. For example if I have an Address table that can be associated to a record in either a Person or Company table. The Address table would have an OwnerType of "Person" or "Company" where the OwnerId referred to the respective PersonId or CompanyId respectively. This isn't a proper normalized structure as the OwnerId cannot have a FK to both PersonId and CompanyId in an either-or capacity, so we cannot set up a proper navigation property. SQL statements can still be written to perform a JOIN on these columns, but we cannot set up a navigation property so we can use `Join()` to link these tables with a condition on the OwnerType.

In terms of flattening related data through navigation properties, you need neither `Include` nor `Join`. Simply use `Select` to project the new structure you want, whether an anonymous type or something like a POCO DTO/ViewModel. So long as you follow the rules where EF can compose the SQL, such as not calling custom methods, accessing `NotMapped` properties, or things like Static extension methods etc. then EF will build the SQL statement with the required JOINs automatically to retrieve the flattened data you request. This can aggregate data as well with Linq methods like `Count()`, `Any()`, etc. and be selective. For example, if I want actor details with a count of their movies and their most recent movie details:

```
var actorDetails = await _context.Actors
    .Select(x => new ActorDetailDTO
    {
        ActorId = x.Id,
        Name = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName,
        TotalMovies = x.Movies.Count(),
        TotalLeadMovies = x.Movies.Where(m => m.MovieDetails.LeadActorId == x.Id).Count(),
        LatestMovie = x.Movies.OrderByDecending(m => m.ReleaseDate)
            .Select(m => new MovieDTO
            {
                MovieId = m.Id,
                Name = m.Name,
                ReleaseDate = m.ReleaseDate
            }).FirstOrDefault()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Note that there is no need to include Movie or MovieDetails, EF will work out what tables to join and return based on the properties and navigation properties in the Linq query.

Now if you do want to flatten unrelated data then you would use `Joins` prior to the `Select`, but the documentation for `Join` should be pretty clear how that would work. Essentially you have to give it a Left hand and a right hand side, then tell EF exactly what it should be considering as the output, whether the resulting Left and right entity pair, or the projected details from the combination.